# Partition not working on the source table after created a materialized view

Tags: google-bigquery

The screenshot should be quite self-explanatory.

[image]

After I created a materialized view "processed_sessions_cust" the partition doesn't work on its source table "processed_sessions".

Whenever I run a query with a partition field it would still process all 150GB which is the size of the entire table. One day should be around 1 GB of data.

Comment: Are the materialized view also partitioned ? could you please show the details of it ?
have you tried to make your query with `WHERE DATE(date)="2021-10-21"` instead of only using the date field ?

Comment: @ewertonvsilva nope, that didn't change anything.

Comment: I reproduced and scenario with an partitioned table and created different materialized views on it and its working as expected. Seams something is wrong with your partitions. Do the following to check them, change the sql editor to Legacy SQL and run the following query: `SELECT * FROM [<project>.<dataset>.<table>$__PARTITIONS_SUMMARY__];` you have to see a list with all the partitions for each day. If not, your partitions are corrupted and not working properly. Please share the results if possible

Comment: thanks @ewertonvsilva - partitions look fine. I can see a partition for yesterday and querying this data with the date filter will still process the entire table (170GB).

Comment: It seems like this is a very specific issue which cannot be easily replicated. I followed the steps of creating a partitioned table and a materialized view on it and for me it worked normally. As I can see there is already an Issue Tracker with a similar issue report (based on the screen it might be created by the OP), which can be found [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/203677555). Best option is to wait for a response from that Issue Tracker.